# Plotting with specific window in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to print the error ratio of the Hilbert matrix.

I'm trying to make the **x axis** `3 → 9` and the **y axis** rather for a `large range`:

```
8.71244799e+01   6.44297999e+02   4.50711567e+03   3.04673758e+04
2.01144882e+05   1.30525476e+06   8.35964228e+06
```

I'm struggling adjust the window, or plotting correctly for that.

Any help would be great!

Here is my attempt at plotting (something)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plot = 6
plt.xlabel ('n')
plt.ylabel ('Error Ration')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for a in range (0, plot, 1):
    y = xratio[a]
    x = plot + 3
    ax.plot(x,y, mfc='orange', mec='orange', marker='.')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use:

```
ax.set_xlim([x_min, x_max])
ax.set_ylim([y_min, y_max])
```